# what is the precedence of a ternary operator in this example?

Tags: python, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for c in "##.#.":
...     count = count + 1 if c == '.' else 0
... 
>>> print(count)
1
>>> count = 0
>>> for c in "##.#.":
...     count = count + (1 if c == '.' else 0)
... 
>>> print(count)
2
```

Why doesn't the first example print out a counter of 2?

Comment: If the second one is your intention, then why not use `count += 1 if c == '.' else 0` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional expressions have [a very low precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

So the first expression is actually parsed as:

```
count = (count + 1) if c == '.' else 0
```

That will set `count` to 0 every time `c != '.'`.

Comment: No, it sets `count` to 0 when `c` *isn't* equal to `'.'`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think I realised that `and` and `or` don't have equal precedence (and similarly bitwise equivalents), though as I always err on the side of more parentheses rather than fewer, I've never been bitten by it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `count` value gets replaced

```
>>> for c in "##.#.":
...     count = count + 1 if c == '.' else 0
...     print (count)
... 
0
0
1
0
1
```

Here `count` gets append

```
>>> count=0
>>> for c in "##.#.":
...     count = count + (1 if c == '.' else 0)
...     print (count)
... 
0
0
1
1
2
>>>
```

Answer (score -3):

Because this corresponds to the True state of if.

`(True) if (Condition) else (Else)`

`count = count + 1 if c == '.' else 0` True status for this (count + 1)

`count + (1 if c == '.' else 0)` True status for this (1)

Did I tell you a little bit complicated?